# How to run multiple programs using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I like to run two programs using batch file, but the condition is, the second program must start only after the first program loaded, so is there any way to control using timer to control when the program starts.

Comment: You can't do this in a batch file as a batch file blocks until the current command finishes. I suggest you write a wrapper app which starts both programs.

Comment: @Joey: That's right, but a little bit short :-) You can use `start` or pipes or if the program is a windows exe it simply works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically, you could try this approach (not tested):

1. Run the first program using the `start` command.
2. Check the task list in a loop to see if the program has appeared there.
3. Impose some time limitation to the said loop.
4. Run the next program in case of success, exit with notification otherwise.

The scripting might look like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
START program1.exe
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,100) DO (
  (TASKLIST | FIND /I "program.exe") && GOTO :startnext

  :: you might add here some delaying
)
ECHO Timeout waiting for program1.exe to start
GOTO :EOF

:startnext
program2.exe
:: or START program2.exe
```

Keep in mind that the timing is not precise, especially if you are going to insert delays between the task list checks.

Answer (score 26):

I needed the same thing, and found out that following thing works as hoped:

```
start D:\Michal\Xming\Xming.exe -multiwindow
start D:\Michal\Xming\putty.exe
start D:\Michal\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe
```

And it all is saved in file Login.bat.

BTW, I am running Win7 but I doubt that this has any impact.

Comment: worked on windows 10 as well for Visual Studio

Answer (score 12):

I think this might be irrelevant here but would like share the following:

I 've created the following batch file and run it whenever I open my laptop in the office to open relevant programs at a single click.
Kept this file at Desktop and created a folder where I put all shortcuts for relevant programs.
So, I run these shortcuts in the batch file as follows:

```
@ECHO off

start C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Softwares\IE
start C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Softwares\Googletalk
start C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Softwares\YahooMessenger
start C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Softwares\Program4
start C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Softwares\Program5
```

Answer (score 6):

I have also find a small hack to do it, just using a ping command with -n switch as follows:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobile Partner\" MobilePartner.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 8
start /d "F:\Other Applcations\System Tools\OS Tweak\" dragfullwindows.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this answer as I am on Windows 10 and it is 2021.
And this provides a few more ideas for newage programs, that should run in the taskbar(in the background).

Here is my "**Work Start.bat**" batch file sitting on my desktop:

```
rem   Work Start Batch Job from Desktop
rem   Launchs All Work Apps
@echo off
rem start "Start VS Code" "C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe"
start "Start OneDrive" "C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"
start  "Start Google Sync" "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\GoogleDriveSync.exe"
start "Start Clipboard" "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCClipboard.exe"
start "Start Cisco AnyConnect" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"
start chrome
start firefox
start skype
start "Start Teams" "C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe" /MIN
start Slack
start Zoom
sleep 10
taskkill /IM "explorer.exe"
taskkill /IM "teams.exe"
taskkill /IM "skype.exe"
taskkill /IM "slack.exe"
taskkill /IM "zoom.exe"
taskkill /IM "cmd.exe"
@echo on
```

**Some Apps would not start with a simple "start app"** command, so I used the full path.
For some reason some were found in my user appdata folder and not in program files, I do not understand this behaviour of program storage, it makes no sense.

I used a **time delay** so that the apps could fully start before I sent them to the background using taskkill command
I killed explorer.exe because OneDrive opens explorer
I killed cmd.exe because it opened and stayed opened due to badly behaving apps.
The rest I killed so that they would just move to the background.

Here is my "**Work End.bat**" batch file to forceably close everything:

```
rem   Work End Batch Job from Desktop
rem   Forcibly Closes All Work Apps
@echo off
taskkill /f /IM OneDrive.exe
taskkill /f /IM GoogleDriveSync.exe
taskkill /f /IM BCClipboard.exe
taskkill /f /IM "vpnui.exe"
taskkill /f /IM "chrome.exe"
taskkill /f /IM "firefox.exe"
taskkill /IM "explorer.exe"
taskkill /f /IM "teams.exe"
taskkill /f /IM "skype.exe"
taskkill /f /IM "slack.exe"
taskkill /f /IM "zoom.exe"
@echo on
```

I do have to **ensure I have saved all my work**, and that files are no longer syncing.
Possibly I will need a batch file that kills everything except file sync.
The good thing about forceably killing Chrome and firefox is they ask to be restored on next start, so I can continue where I left off, assuming I saved everything.
If I don't forceably kill these they stay in the background, if I close using the Cross they do not offer me to start from where I left off.

I could then start my gaming files, in another batch file but this would be similar to the first file.

Now I can turn off the default "Start Up" Apps and use this "Work Start.bat" , because the Start Up Apps annoy me when I start my pc just to game.